# How to list items by "type" in Django view

Tags: django

First of all I am very new to Django and this is a simple question. I apologize  but I can't seem to be able to word a search correctly to find an answer. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

fyi: Django version is 1.3.7

I have a simple inventory app in the works and am creating a view that would list items by device type (eg: Tablet), and model type (eg: iPad Air or iPad 2). I want to be able to list all instances of a device type and have the results sorted by model. For example my page would look something like this:

**TABLETS:**

**iPad's Airs:**

**-  list of ALL iPads Airs**

**iPad 2's:**

**-  list of ALL iPad 2's.**

Unfortunately my page displays a single instance of the model type in each list and creates a new list for each device, eg:

**TABLETS:**

**iPad's Airs:**

**-  only single item listed**

**iPad Air's:**

**-  only single item listed**

etc...

**iPad 2's:**

**-  only single item listed**

**iPad 2's:**

**-  only single item listed**

etc...

Here are the entries in my models.py (edited down to just the important bits):

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.device_type

class DeviceModelType(models.Model):
    model_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.model_type

class Device(models.Model):
...
    device_type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType)
    device_model = models.ForeignKey(DeviceModelType)
    name_of_device = models.CharField(max_length=25)
...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s' % (self.name_of_device, self.manufacturer, self.device_model)
```

here is my view:

```
def check_out(request, device_id):
    available_device_list = Device.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render_to_response('inventory/list.html', {'available_device_list': available_device_list, })
```

and my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Inventory Test{% endblock title %}
{% block head %}Inventory Test{% endblock head %}
{% block content %}
<p><h3>Inventory:</h3></p>
{% for Device in available_device_list %}
{{ Device.device_model }}'s:
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventory/device_checkout.html".{{ Device.device_model }}<strong>{{ Device.name_of_device }}</strong></a>
</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
{% block footer %}
<p>
<hr/><br/>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/">admin</a></p>
{% endblock footer %}
```

Comment: did you migrate your database properly? check ur database and see how many Device in there.

Comment: There is no database to migrate really, I am creating from scratch. There are currently only a few example devices entered just to test the app.